# How to read XML document with JiBX?

Tags: java, xml, jibx

I try to do example code

```
public class xml_class {
    /**
     * Unmarshal the sample document from a file, compute and set order total, then
     * marshal it back out to another file.
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // unmarshal customer information from file
            IBindingFactory bfact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(test.Order.class);
            IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bfact.createUnmarshallingContext();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:/liferay-develop/data1.xml");
            Order order = (Order)uctx.unmarshalDocument(in, null);

            // compute the total amount of the order
            float total = 0.0f;
            for (Iterator<Item> iter = order.getItems().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Item item = iter.next();
                total += item.getPrice() * item.getQuantity();
            }
            order.setTotal(new Float(total));

            // marshal object back out to file (with nice indentation, as UTF-8)
            IMarshallingContext mctx = bfact.createMarshallingContext();
            mctx.setIndent(2);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:/liferay-develop/out.xml");
            mctx.setOutput(out, null);
            mctx.marshalDocument(order);
            System.out.println("Processed order with " + order.getItems().size() +
                " items and total value " + total);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (JiBXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And get an error:

```
Unable to access binding information for class test.Order
Make sure the binding has been compiled
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: JiBX_bindingList
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
at org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getBindingList(BindingDirectory.java:68)
at org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory.getFactory(BindingDirectory.java:211)
at test.xml_class.main(xml_class.java:31)
```

What is binding? And how to use it?

Comment: Binding defines how your XML structure corresponds to your Java object. I think that [JiBX's binding tutorial](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/binding/tutorial/binding-tutorial.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: Im watch them but, my english terrible and its hard to me read so much text. I try Eclipse JiBX plugin. But nothing is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eli,
Why don't you start with a simple example.
Here is a nice one to start with:
https://github.com/jibx/maven-plugin/tree/master/test-suite/base-binding-test
Check this out, build it, and run the simple marshalling/unmarshalling example in the org.jibx.schema.test.person project.
I hope this helps.
Don